# How to write a Custom field Validation for ModelSerializers in Django Rest Framework(DRF) similar to Form Validation in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-validation, django-serializer

I am currently creating an api based on DRF.I have a model which is like:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    description = models.TextField()
    text = models.TextField(blank = False, default = "this is my text" )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and the corresponding Serializer for this model is as :

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('name','description','completed','text')
```

Now my question is that I want to validate the 'name' field of my model while taking up data. 
For instance I may end checking the first name or second name of the user by a Python code similar to a Django Form:

```
def clean_name(self):
    name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
    first,second = name.split(' ')
    if second is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter full name")
```

I know of something called 'validate_(fieldname)' in Serializers.serializer class. But I want this to be used in Serializers.ModelSerializer instead.(Just similar to the custom forms validation in Django)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can **add a `validate_name()` method to your serializer** which will perform this validation. It should return the validated value or raise a `ValidationError`.

To perform the check whether user has entered a full name or not, we will use `str.split()` which will return all the words in the string. If the no. of words in the string is not greater than 1, then we will raise a `ValidationError`. Otherwise, we return the `value`.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_name(self, value):
        """
        Check that value is a valid name.
        """
        if not len(value.split()) > 1: # check name has more than 1 word
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter full name") # raise ValidationError
        return value
```

Comment: Is there anything similar to cleaned_data in serializers?

Comment: Yes, there exists `serializer.validated_data` which is accessible after `.is_valid()` has been called on the serializer.

Comment: You can also use `validators` parameter in a field in model class, DRF will make use that as well. Helpful in enforcing a global validation. This answer is correct as well.